# Binding to child object

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding, nested

I have the following code(wp7-silverlight). I try to bind a slider to those 2 controls' Angle property, but for some reason the inner control doesn't seems to receive the data, only the parent control. When I put them side by side(not nested), those work properly. Any idea why only the outer control can get the data from the slider?

```
 <rotate:RotatableUserControl Width="400"
                                         Height="400"
                                         x:Name="RotatableUserControl"
                                         Angle="{Binding ElementName=SliderObject, Path=Value}">

                <Canvas Background="Red">
                    <rotate:RotatableUserControl Width="50"
                                                 Height="50"
                                                 x:Name="childeRotate3"
                                                 Angle="{Binding ElementName=SliderObject, Path=Value}">
                        <Grid Background="Yellow" />
                    </rotate:RotatableUserControl>
                </Canvas>
            </rotate:RotatableUserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you can't bind it nested, but you could try to set the canvas Datacontext to the SliderObject and the bind the Value to the nested rotate:RotatableUserControl, that may work!

```
 <rotate:RotatableUserControl Width="400"
                                     Height="400"
                                     x:Name="RotatableUserControl"
                                     Angle="{Binding ElementName=SliderObject, Path=Value}">

            <Canvas Background="Red" Datacontext={Binding ElementName=SliderObject, Path=Value}">
                <rotate:RotatableUserControl Width="50"
                                             Height="50"
                                             x:Name="childeRotate3"
                                             Angle="{Binding}">
                    <Grid Background="Yellow" />
                </rotate:RotatableUserControl>
            </Canvas>
        </rotate:RotatableUserControl>
```